# How to disable autolink of textview programmatically in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have set the `autolink` of the textview to phone. But at some place of the app I have to disable the autolink of the textview programmatically.
How can I do that in Xamarin.Android. (In Android you have the option "none", but this option doesn't exist in Xamarin.Android).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no none option in Xamarin, but you can get the same functionality by setting the value to `autolink = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have found a bug in Xamarin.Android regarding the missing "none" option. You should file a bug report at [bugzilla.xamarin.com](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

In general the textview has a property named autolink which can be set with something from the enum Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.